# AngularJS ForEach against REST/JSON call ($resource) is undefined/running before JSON is ready?

Tags: arrays, json, angularjs

I am trying to run a foreach against a resource via a controller in order to output each of the items in the JSON array (later I will add conditionals), but it is returning as "undefined":

```
 pfcControllers.controller('pfcArticlesCtrl', ['$scope', '$log', 'pfcArticles', function ($scope, $log, pfcArticles) {
$scope.articlecount = pfcArticles.query();

var val = [];

angular.forEach($scope.articlecount, function (value, key) {
    this.push(value);
}, val);
    console.log(val);
    $scope.temp = val;
```

}]);

However, if I create a static array as follows, it works as expected:

```
pfcControllers.controller('pfcArticlesCtrl', ['$scope', '$log', 'pfcArticles', function ($scope, $log, pfcArticles) {
$scope.articlecount = pfcArticles.query();

articlz = [{ title: 'art1', id: 1}]

var val = [];
// Look over categories
angular.forEach(articlz, function (value, key) {
    this.push(value);
}, val);
    console.log(val);
    $scope.temp = val;

}]);
```

Here is my resource:

```
    pfcServices.factory('pfcArticles', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('https://myrestcall.net/tables/articles', {},
    {
        'update': { method: 'PATCH' }
    }
    );
}]);
```

What I believe is happening is that my foreach is executing before the JSON is returned since it is most likely async. How do I have it wait until my JSON is ready to be looped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for something like the following:

```
pfcControllers.controller('pfcArticlesCtrl', ['$scope', '$log', 'pfcArticles', function ($scope, $log, pfcArticles) {
    var articles = pfcArticles.query(function() {
        $scope.articlecount = articles.length;
        var val = [];

        angular.forEach(articles, function (value, key) {
            this.push(value);
        }, val);

        $scope.temp = val;
    });
}]);
```

The reason you are logging `undefined` is because the call to `query()` is asynchronous. You need to specify what to do with the articles in the resolve handler for the query.